# Rails ActiveRecord update_all array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord Model called Animal.
Animal has id and client_id.
In my app have an array called @selectedanimals that contains the id's of the animals I want to update such as: @selectedanimals: ["6", "14", "5"].
I have the value of a new client_id for these animals like @newclient.id and I want to update all of these Animal records with the new client_id.
What I have now is:

```
Animal.update_all({:client_id => @transferclient.id}, {:id => @selecteanimals})
```

I know this is not 100% correct because it is having a problem with :id.
I get an error like this:
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 8 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Forgive my ignorance but this is my first time using update_all and I don't see any examples where you pass it an array of the ids of the records you want to update so any help would be appreciated much.

EDIT:
Apparently the @transferclient.id was not properly defined. That was my problem.
Thanks all.

Comment: Are you trying to update with single client_id or  multiple client_id's ?

Comment: single client_id and multiple animals - but, I found that the real issue with the code was that @transferclient.id was not properly defined.

Comment: Does @Danpe's answer work ?

Comment: It might work but the code I have listed in my question worked just fine once I properly defined @transferclient.id.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Ruby so I don't know if there's been some recent change in the API but [Danpe's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509240/rails-activerecord-update-all-array-of-ids#19509308) answer as well as the initial suggestion that actually worked according to the asker, didn't work for me. They both raised a syntax error.

The solution that worked for me and is actually proposed in the API documentation is this:

```
Animal.where(:id => @selectedanimals).update_all(:client_id => @transferclient.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if id is inside that array:

```
Animal.update_all({:client_id => @transferclient.id}, {"id IN (?)" , @selecteanimals})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the code I had in my question worked once I properly defined @transferclient.id. That was my problem.